# Upgrading to Elasticsearch 5.2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following legacy mapping code that works in ES 1.7 but fails in 5.2. The things that fail are multi_field is not supported as well as path. The documentation mentions that these fields were removed but fails to provide the remedy beyond suggesting to use copy_to. Cans someone give a bit more details on that.

```
{
"sample": {
    "_parent": {
        "type": "security"
    },
    "properties": {
        "securityDocumentId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "include_in_all": false
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "path": "full",
            "fields": {
                "indexer_sample_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "include_in_all": false
                }
            }
        },
        "sampleid": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "path": "just_name",
            "fields": {
                "sampleid": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "sample.sampleid": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "sample.sampleid.sort": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort_analyzer"
                },
                "sample.sampleid.name.autocomplete": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

The `path` option's default value was `full`, so you can leave it out since it way deprecated in 2.0. The `path` value `just_name` doesn't exist anymore and you MUST reference all your fields by their full path name. The multi-fields can be rewritten very simply:

```
{
"sample": {
    "_parent": {
        "type": "security"
    },
    "properties": {
        "securityDocumentId": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "include_in_all": false
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "indexer_sample_id": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "include_in_all": false
                }
            }
        },
        "sampleid": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "sampleid": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "sample.sampleid": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "sample.sampleid.sort": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort_analyzer"
                },
                "sample.sampleid.name.autocomplete": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                }
            }
        },
```

Note that I'm not sure of the usefulness and added value of the `id` sub-fields